# High dimensional beta integral (question following the previous post)

Tags: harmonic-analysis, fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions

Hello,

This post is a question following the previous [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72525/high-dimensional-beta-integral-a-typo-in-steins-book-singular-integrals). In one dimensional case, we have
$$
\int_0^x |y|^{1-\alpha} |x-y|^{1-\beta} d y = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)} |x|^{-1+\alpha+\beta},\quad x>0
$$
for $\alpha\in [0,1[$, $\beta\in [0,1[$, and $\alpha+\beta <1$. What is interesting is that we do can take $\alpha+\beta=1$, and then the above integral is actually independent of $x$. 
This is the benefit of integration over $[0,x]$ instead of $R$.

My problem is then whether we could generalize the above integral to high dimensional case? In particular, by
choosing $\alpha+\beta=1$, the generalized integral is expected to be independent of $x\in R^d_+$.

Thanks for any hints!

Anand

Comment: Are you by any chance looking for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_integral

Comment: @Suvrit, thank you for your hint. I will check whether Selberg integral can save me instead of struggling with the beta integral. :-)